# Format as table (TableStyles) in Excel VSTO 2007, error: one table cannot overlap another table

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I am making an add-in and I am trying to format the output which my add-in generates,using Format as table table-styles provided by Excel.

The one which you get on the 'home tab' --> 'Format as Table' button on the ribbon.

I am using following code:

```
SourceRange.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
 SourceRange, System.Type.Missing, xlYesNo, System.Type.Missing).Name =
 TableName;

SourceRange.Select();

SourceRange.Worksheet.ListObjects[TableName].TableStyle = TableStyleName;
```

TableStyleName is any style name like TableStyleMedium17, you get it if you just hover a particular style in Excel.

My problem is that, even if I keep the `SourceRange` as 10 columns, all the columns right till the end get selected and are considered as one table.
Because of that the table I populate right next to it is also considered as a part of the first table that was generated.Since, both the table have same column names excel automatically changes the column names in all the following tables that are generated.
Also, because I am generating the tables in a loop after 2 tables are generated I get the error :

> A table cannot overlap another table.

PS: I am clearly mentioning `SourceRange` as:

```
var startCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[startRow, startCol];
var endCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[endRow, endCol];
var SourceRange = worksheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell);
```

Kindly suggest a way out.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to figure out what was happening on our end for this:

on the 
    `xlWorkbook.Worksheets.Add([before],[after], Type.Missing, Type.Missing)` 
call, we had to flip before and after since we wanted the sheets to move right, not left and then accessed 
    `xlWorkbook.Worksheets[sheetCount]`
by increasing sheetcount for however many sheets were being generated.

Having it the other way was creating the worksheet to access a previously assigned table formatfrom the `SourceRange.Worksheet.ListObjects[TableName].TableStyle = TableStyleName` call.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got around this problem a week after posting this, sorry did not update in the rush of things.
This actually is an in built excel functionality.
You cant help it, the excel application will keep doing this.
So, ultimately wrote my own table styles in c# and applied it to the excel range which is mentioned as ***SourceRange***. Its just like writing CSS.
If you are interested in knowing the details of that comment it on this question itself or you can contact me by email from my profile.